# What if V+ = V- with an OpAmp?

Tags: operational-amplifier

In the two simulations below, Vout is almost the same (to GND) in both while the OpAmp sees the same differences in potential at its inputs, so actually, the second output should be 1V lower. How is that possible?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB7VIR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: how does a wall switch know what 240V is?     ............... your question is unclear ..... please try a different wording

Comment: There is no absolute voltage.  Only voltage with respect to something else.  When we say "0V", it's shorthand for "zero volts with respect to whatever circuit node we have defined as the reference".  That reference is usually "ground", but that ground may not be the potential of the actual ground you're standing on (or orbiting over, or whatever).

Comment: question edited

Comment: Yes, to ground. @dim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBM5U4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. OP's schematic redrawn with more realistic power supplies.*

> In the two simulations below, Vout is almost the same (to GND) in both while the OpAmp sees the same differences in potential at its inputs, so actually, the second output should be 1V lower. How is that possible?

You have two big problems with your schematics:

1. The supply voltages are way too low - particularly for a TL081. You will see this in the datasheet.
2. You have no feedback on your circuit so the op-amp output will be the "open-loop gain" (> 1,000,000) times the difference between the two inputs. You have shorted them together and you are probably expecting a zero output as a result. Real op-amps aren't perfect, however, so the very slight differences between the two inputs - known as the input offset voltage - will cause the output to swing as hard as it can towards one supply rail or the other depending on the polarity of the difference.

With such low supply voltages the output will probably get stuck at about half-supply voltage.

Note that simulation results will vary with the quality of the simulator. Some will give realistic simulation of details like input offset voltage and various other non-ideal characteristics. Operation at very slow supply voltages may be one of the conditions that may not be simulated well.

Comment: It's probably worth including the term *input offset voltage* somewhere in this answer.

Comment: Excellent thought. I knew it was missing that little bit of something!

Comment: I'm actually not talking about practical use of this, just the theory. Afaik the Output Voltage of an OpAmp is equal to the gain * the difference of the input voltages (in this case 0). My question now is what this output voltage is referenced to. I could only explain to myself that it is referenced to Vdd (but then the output voltage in the sim. would have to be Vdd not 0V) as the OpAmp "doesn't know" where I put my ground reference (this is what I tried to show with the two circuits) but appareantly I'm wrong. But I don't know where, which drives me crazy as this seems - for me - paradoxical

Comment: @aquaatic Intuitively to me, an ideal op-amp with zero potential difference between its inputs will be smack-dab in the middle of its range. So an ideal op-amp (with an infinite positive and negative rail voltage) will be 0V. What happens if you run your simulation with asymmetric voltage supplies?

Comment: in purely theoretic terms, *it's undefined*.

Comment: I.e. all your idealized op-amp models only make sense if you don't do an open-loop configuration. Your setting violates the condition of the simplistic "golden Opamp rules", so you can't have a theoretic value for a setting that's not covered by the theory.

Comment: @aquaatic Here is a way to think about it, that explains why it's undefined: the opamp's job is simple: it tries, by adjusting its output, to null out its input voltage difference. If the non-inverting input is higher than the inverting input, it drives its output harder to the positive supply rail. If the inverting input is higer than the non-inverting, it drives its output harder to the negative rail. If it's zero, it's happy, and it tries to maintain that situation. Now, in your case, it's always happy, whatever the output is. So the output could be anywhere. Hence, undefined.